# Is it possible to use Subversion Edge with nginx or lighttpd instead of Apache2?

Tags: svn, nginx

Is it possible to run Subversion Edge using nginx instead of Apache2? I'm trying to migrate away from using Apache2 for my IT projects, and nginx seems to be the best performing server I can find.

I need to use Subversion Edge as our project managers like having a user interface to create and manage repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Because only Apache's DAV and SVN modules exist for http-served repositories

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Subversion Edge without apache but you can use built in apache to run Subversion Edge on some random port and use nginx as proxy for this apache.